# Disable Chrome Developer Tools' $ function

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, developer-tools

Chrome Developer Tools define a convenient `$` function (as well as a few other conveniences). When using jQuery, however, it is convenient to have `$ = jQuery`. Is it possible to disable Chrome's autodefined `$` function without disabling the more convenient definitions (like `$0`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome's autodefined `$` is supplanted by any function that may be on the page. Open a console on StackOverflow, for instance, and type `$ === jQuery` and you should get `true`. Unless I've misunderstood you, there is no need to disable Chrome's default `$` to make room for other functions.

Comment: I guess I ran into an intermittent bug because I'm using the dev channel, and `$` did override jQuery's `$`. I now see it doesn't do that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for jQuery.noConflict().  See here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/